# On Windows 7, want to disconnect Yahoo Messenger but not Yahoo Mail

Tags: email

I have a laptop with Windows 7. I'm a novice to all computer jargon, I only want to disconnect Yahoo Messenger and still keep my Yahoo mail. I need instructions, hopefully I'll understand.

Comment: You might want to check your Caps key when you're done fiddling with Yahoo Mail. Or before. Before would be better.

Comment: Definitely before! Yahoo! does not take lightly to all caps or even the simple omission of exclamation marks.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean on the site itself? If so, there should be an option on the left side of your email window to sign off/log out of the chat.

Answer (score 0):

If you mean on the site itself, as Ryan has said there should be an option to turn off chat either on the chat box, on the bottom of the page or in the yahoo mail settings. If you are talking about the desktop messenger program, to be logged into email and not available to chat with your friends go into "invisible" mode. This will make others think you are offline when you are not.